# What is the reason for the error ‘high-bound for max-jOPS is measured to be 0’ when run specjbb2015

Tags: java, linux, testing, java-8

used the default args
RAM： 126G
CPU： 4way-16Core-2.5Hz

Run with no JVM_OPTS, SPEC_OPTS ......
Here is the log:

```
    64s: (validation=PASSED) Property settings are COMPLIANT.
    64s: 
    64s: Searching for high-bound for max-jOPS possible for this system
    64s: Searching from base IR = 100
    64s:       rampup IR =      0 [reconfig (term) (init) ] ... (rIR:aIR:PR = 0:0:0) (tPR = 0) [OK] 
   118s:       rampup IR =     10 ... (rIR:aIR:PR = 10:13:13) (tPR = 1148) [OK] 
   123s:       rampup IR =     20 ... (rIR:aIR:PR = 20:17:17) (tPR = 1346) [OK] 
   126s:       rampup IR =     30 .... (rIR:aIR:PR = 30:29:29) (tPR = 2305) [OK] 
   131s:       rampup IR =     40 .??????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????. (rIR:aIR:PR = 40:0:0) (tPR = 25) [IR is under limit] [PR is under limit] 
   215s: Re-initializing (term) (init) ... OK
   262s: high-bound for max-jOPS is measured to be 0
   262s: 
   262s: Failed to continue on zero high-bound
   262s: 
   262s: (term... (rIR:aIR:PR = 0:0:0) (tPR = 0) [OK] 
   265s: ) Tests are skipped.
   265s: 
   265s: Generating level 0 report from ./specjbb2015-C-20210311-00001.data.gz
```